# Laravel 5.1 - adding middleware in a route replacing controller method with closure

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am setting middleware property in my routes. I am hoping to handle the login in the middleware so that by the time the control reaches the controller method,
I will have the user data will be available. In the `routes.php` file I have added the following statement.

```
Route::get('users/find',['middleware'=>'jwt.auth','UsersController@show'])->name('users.find');
```

I was hoping that  the above statement will make the route point to

> UsersController@show

, but it is pointing to a Closure when i checked using route:list
command. Please advice on how to make the route point to the controller method. It was behaving as expected when there was no middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `uses` key:

```
Route::get('users/find', ['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'uses' => 'UsersController@show'])
->name('users.find');
```